# Lottery number generator

Tags: beginner, ruby, array, random

```
def getRandomNumbers(count, min, max)
  array = []

    while array.length < count
      tmp = rand(max) + min
      if array.include?(tmp)
        next
      else
        array.push(tmp)
      end
    end

  return array
end


def prettyPrint(someArray)
  string = ""
  someArray.each do |item|
    string += item.to_s + "\t"
  end
  puts string
end

array = getRandomNumbers(6, 1, 49)
prettyPrint(array)
```

I'm just learning Ruby and wrote this little two functions just to play around and get a feel for Ruby syntax etc.
I wanted a function that generates a given amount of random numbers within certain limits. In this example for 6 lottery numbers, therefore each number should only occur once. The second method is pretty self explanatory.

The code runs and does what he is supposed to do. However, what are nice tweaks and tricks to make this code nicer and utilizing the abilities of Ruby?

Answer (score 6):

A min-max pair would be slightly better represented using a `Range`.  In fact, starting with Ruby 1.9, `rand` can accept a range.

The loop can be written a bit more succinctly.

The pretty-printing function should also be written in one line instead.

`lower_case` is a more conventional naming convention.  An explicit `return` is not necessary, as the code returns the last value anyway.

```
def get_random_numbers(range, count=1)
  array = []
  while array.length < count
    n = rand(range)
    array.push(n) unless array.include?(n)
  end
  array
end

def pretty_print(array)
  puts array.join("\t")
end

pretty_print(get_random_numbers(1..49, 6)
```

Comment: Great. Those are the things I was looking for. Wasn't aware of "unless" so far. However thank you, this is a good starting point to dive in more deeply in to the concepts of ruby.

Comment: The naming convention is typically called `snake_case` not `lower_case`, see [style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#snake-case-symbols-methods-vars)

Answer (score 4):

## A simplification

The `Array` class has the `sample` method, which does a lot of the work for you: it picks a number of items randomly from the array with no duplicates. It's perfect for your scenario.

```
def random_numbers(range, count=1)
  range.to_a.sample(count)
end
```

Notes:

- I renamed the method using underscores, the preferred convention in Ruby. Also, prefixes like 'get' and 'set' are generally not used.
- I used the range parameter that @200_success used, I like the way you call it.
- I converted the range to an array to use the `sample` method.

I recommend becoming very familiar with all the methods in the `Array` and `Enumerable` classes, it will pay huge dividends in your Ruby code!

As for pretty-printing, I wouldn't even bother with a method, as I think this is clear enough:

```
puts random_numbers(1..49, 6).join "\t"
```

## Alternative: Using a Class

I realize this was a learning exercise, but let's say this lottery picker was something being written professionally. In that case, I'd recommend modeling it with a class. There are many reasons to do this; it nicely encapsulates the logic and actions, it provides an interface for reuse (e.g. other people can use it), and it provides a place to put lottery-related code (in case you wanted to get fancy with your output, for example).

In Ruby, it is very easy to do. Here's a start:

```
class Lottery
  attr :numbers

  def initialize
    @numbers = (1..49).to_a
  end

  def pick(n=1)
    numbers.sample(n).sort
  end

  def pick_winner
    puts "The winning numbers are:"
    puts pick(6).join "\t"
    puts "And the powerball is: #{pick}"
  end
end
```

You would use it like this:

```
game = Lottery.new
game.pick 6 #=> [2, 6, 14, 25, 32, 45]
game.pick 6 #=> [10, 14, 22, 27, 34, 43]
game.pick_winner
The winning numbers are:
4       11      12      15      16      38
And the powerball is: [7]
```

Comment: Wow I'm stunned. So basically we got down to 2 lines of instructions. I begin to grasp the potential of ruby. :)

Comment: Indeed! You would be surprised the number of things that can be boiled down to 2 lines. Developers coming from other languages are surprised to hear guidelines like [methods should be no longer than 5 lines](https://gist.github.com/henrik/4509394) but it is not only possible, it is truly better: that conciseness often increases clarity.

Comment: I added another option, using a class.

Comment: I would expect the object to be stateful. In other words, successive calls to `pick` on the same object should not result in duplicates. Otherwise, there is no advantage over the simple function.

Comment: Thank you very much. One question though just to be sure: in the method definition i can even declare a standard value for my parameters. Is that right?

Comment: @200_success I'm not sure what you mean. The `pick` method represents a lottery ticket. If we both go to the store and buy a ticket, we could end up with some of the same numbers, no?

Comment: @Frommel If you're referring to the default value of a parameter, the answer is yes. The pick method in my example defaults to 1.

Comment: I think what 200_success is trying to say, that u made a class that represents a lottery, not a lottery ticket. Meaning if we draw 6 balls, we might want to be able to to look at those numbers at some point later. Therefore we should save the six numbers and return those on a pick call or even providing seperate methods for last_draw and new_draw.

Comment: Yep, that's why I said "here's a start". I offered a minimal class to show things like class attributes, the `initialize` method, etc. Giving it more functionality is an exercise left to the reader :)

Comment: Though the class stuff is a little bit extended on the initial question, I found it useful.

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually need a loop because Ruby has built in functions that simplifies all this.

To grab `count` random UNIQUE numbers in range `range`, do:

```
def get_random_numbers(range, count=1)
    range.to_a.shuffle[0..count]
end
```

Example:

```
get_random_numbers(0..100,3) # => [34,82,4]
get_random_numbers(0..1000) # => [829]
```

Comment: As others have pointed out, `range.to_a.sample(count)` is more succinct but I'll keep this here as another viable option

Comment: By the way, you don't need to pass a range into this function. `Array` has `to_a` defined as well so you can pass in `[0,4,6,7],2` and it'll do pretty much what you expect

Comment: This solution has one serious drawback: memory consumption. If you want to pick 10 numbers between `1` and `1,000,000` you have to create an Array with a million elements in it. This won't always be a problem, but it's good to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Set` instead of `Array` is faster and checks for presence for you:

```
require "set"

def get_random_numbers count, min, max
  set = Set.new
  set << rand(min..max) until set.size == count
  set.to_a
end
```